# Zero divisor error while calculating average

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a query to get some sales statistics as requested. It works fine for some dates but when i extend the range, it gives me error "ORA-01476 :divisor is equal to zero". I believe this is due to the line where i am calculating the average. I cannot use the built-in avg function as it doesnt give the same value. How can i fix this.

```
select distinct p.product_code, sum(oi.mass_ordered) "TOTAL MASS ORDERED KG",--OI.ROLL_SHEET,
sum(oit2.mass_shipped) "shipped KG",
(sum(oi.price *(OIt2.MASS_shipped) )/sum(oit2.mass_shipped)) "AVERAGE CALCULATED",
sum(oi.price *(OIt2.MASS_shipped/1000) ) "TOTAL ORDER ITEM PRICE" , count(oi.order_item) "ITEM_COUNT"
from product p
left outer join orderitem oi on p.product_code = oi.product_code
left outer join orderheader oh on oi.order_code = oh.order_code
INNER JOIN ORDERITEMTOTAL oit2 on oi.order_code = oit2.order_code and oi.order_item = oit2.order_item
where oh.date_cust_issued between to_date('01/10/2019 00:00' , 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI') and 
to_date('09/10/2019 23:59' , 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI')
group by p.product_code
order by p.product_code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NULLIF()` to avoid divide-by-zero:

```
(sum(oi.price * OIt2.MASS_shipped) /
 nullif(sum(oit2.mass_shipped), 0)
) as "AVERAGE CALCULATED",
```

This turns a `0` denominator into `NULL`, so the expression returns `NULL` instead of an error.